# XPages typeahead takes too long

Tags: xpages, typeahead

When we try typeahead with ftSearch , it takes too long to complete (to be shown on the screen). ftsearch finishes at the same time

```
[0D88:000B-0B44] 30.12.2015 10:03:06   HTTP JVM: Start= 30.12.2015 10:03
[0D88:000B-0B44] 30.12.2015 10:03:06   HTTP JVM: Finish= 30.12.2015 10:03
```

But in the inputbox which has typeahead properties results return more then 5 seconds. I mean It takes too long.

is there any suggestion how to decrease the time

```
'fldDefName = inthe inputbox there is a option for ftSearch named "Var" colNumber = Column Number for results. I generally user [0]
 function getTypeAheadList(vName,frmName,fldName,fldDefName,colNumber) 
{
 var searchView:NotesView = database.getView(vName);'
    var query = "(FIELD Form CONTAINS "+ frmName + " AND FIELD " + fldName + " CONTAINS *" + fldDefName +"*)";
    print("Query= "+query);
    var searchOutput:Array = ["å","åå"];
    var hits = searchView.FTSearch(query);
    var entries = searchView.getAllEntries();
    var entry = entries.getFirstEntry();

    for (i=0; i<hits; i++) 
    {
        searchOutput.push(entry.getColumnValues()[colNumber]);
        entry = entries.getNextEntry();
    }
    searchOutput.sort();

    var result ="<ul><li><span class='informal'></span></li>";
    var limit = Math.min(hits,50);

    for (j=0; j<limit; j++) 
    {
        var name = searchOutput[j].toString();
        var start = name.indexOfIgnoreCase(lupkey)
        var stop = start + lupkey.length;

        name = name.insert("</b>",stop).insert("<b>",start);
        result += "<li>" + name + "</li>"; 
    }

    result += "</ul>";
    return result;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the number of docs that will be returned by FTSearch to 50 with

```
var hits = searchView.FTSearch(query, 50);
```

Right now the search result might contain e.g. 5000 docs and it takes time to push them into searchOutput and to sort. You reduce the hints afterwards to 50 anyway...